# How should I proceed when a complicated question gets an excellent response to part of the question?

Tags: discussion, answers

The sole answer for [Do lower speed limits reduce gasoline usage?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3351/do-lower-speed-limits-reduce-gasoline-usage) fully addresses the core of my question and I would consider it pretty damn close to a complete answer even though it doesn't directly address the rest of the question. Is this a sign that:

- My question is too complicated
- The answer is not complete enough to accept
- ... ?

My instinct is to either upvote *or* accept but not both. The upvote would be for an excellent answer; the accept would be admitting that it is close enough. For some reason I hesitate doing both because I am still unsatisfied with regards to the full extent of what I wanted to know. I don't have a *problem* with this; I am still just trying to understand how to ask and answer questions here.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, I would probably upvote but not accept. While it's a good answer, it doesn't fully answer what was asked in the title: do lower speed limits reduce gasoline usage?

After upvoting his answer, I strongly encourage you to leave a comment on the answer explaining why you did not accept the answer. With a bit of luck, the user will make the appropriate amount of research to completely answer your question (or someone else will, after seeing your comment).

Comment: ...and, in lieu of the author completing their answer, hopefully users are encouraged to wiki-edit the answer to add the additional info for completeness.